# use find to locate, move and symlink a directory tree matching [0-9]{1,10}/*

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression, parameter

I need to move some directories and make symlinks back to them.

The directory structure looks like:

```
/storage1
/storage1/123/named_directory_1
/storage1/123456/named_directory_2
/storage1/123456789/named_directory_3
```

I want to move the ***named*** directories, to matching numbered directories elsewhere, like so:

```
/storage2
/storage2/123/named_directory_1
/storage2/123456/named_directory_2
/storage2/123456789/named_directory_3
```

and then symlink those named directories back. the numbered directories remain as independent directories on each storage, but the named directories should be symlinked from their respective numbered directories on storage1 to the matching numbered directory on storage2.

i worked up a find command that matches what I want: `find . -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -regextype grep -regex ".*/[0-9]\{1,10\}/.*"` which matches all of these:

```
/storage2/123/named_directory_1
/storage2/123456/named_directory_2
/storage2/123456789/named_directory_3
```

but I don't know how to do all the manipulations. something like this, but you can see i have no idea how to get `$number` and `$numberandname`... but I have been experiementing with BASH parameters and substitutions but I can't quite get it right.

```
echo "${named#*/}"
named_directory_1
```

and this one:

```
echo "${named%/*}"
/storage/123
```

here is my best script outline:

```
while read -r named; do
export numberandname="${named#/*/*/*/}"
export number="${numberandname%/*}"
    mv -- "$named" "/storage2/$number/"
    ln -s -- "/storage2/$numberandname "$named"
done < <(find /storage1/ -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -regextype grep -regex ".*/[0-9]\{1,10\}/.*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was add some improvements (in my opinion) to your code.

1) I was used `-printf '%P\n'` option for `find` command and this gave path without `storage1` part.
 2) Removed `export` commands, because it doesn't needed here.

```
#!/bin/bash

src_dir="storage1"
dest_dir="storage2"    

nums_and_names=$(find "$src_dir" -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -regextype grep -regex ".*/[0-9]\{1,10\}/.*" -printf '%P\n')

while read -r named; do
    echo mv -- "${src_dir}/$named" "${dest_dir}/${named%/*}"
    echo ln -s -- "${dest_dir}/$named" "${src_dir}/$named" 
done <<< "$nums_and_names"
```